# Initiating an Embed variable with a string... variable does not exist?

Tags: flash, actionscript, builder

In my actionscript file I have this:

```
[Embed(source="assets/disk.png")]
protected static const Disk:Class;
```

if I try to create a class with the following:

```
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName("Disk") as Class;
```

I get an error that "Disk" does not exist.   Is there a way to initiate the Disk class by name so it is creating a new instance of that by using a string?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Can't fully determine what you're trying to do.. If you're loading an image and expecting it to be accessed the same as a class, this is incorrect. If you've created the class Disk and want to create an instance of it using a string "Disk", then this is possible. If the latter, you're on the right track and I can give you a more elaborate piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the `Disk` - it's a class and can be instantiated:

```
var diskInstance:ByteArray = new Disk();
```

(it will be ByteArrayAsset because mime type is not specified in Embed.)
Embed will generate class with long obscure name, you can't get it without parsing swf, so use Disk const instead.
**Update**:
As I understand, you want to embed resource and give it specific class name. AFAIK, that's not possible. You can though create class Disk yourself and put Embed inside:

```
public class Disk {
    [Embed(source="assets/disk.png")]
    public static const content:Class;
}
```

Then you can get Disk class by name and use content property to create instance.

Comment: I want to be able to initiate it using a string

Comment: Why as a string? Maybe try:
new this.['Disk']() as Bitmap;

Answer (score 0):

Close, but you need to tweak it just a little, like this:

```
var str:String = "MyObject";

var Shell:Class = getDefinitionByName(str) as Class;
var myobj:DisplayObject = new Shell();

addChild(myobj);
```

Something to note, this line:

```
var myobj:DisplayObject = new Shell();
```

You should replace `DisplayObject` with the most primitive type you can (I generally use my own base class).

Other things to note:

You'll need to have the full package path when using `getDefinitionByName`. eg:

```
getDefinitionByName("flash.display.MovieClip");
```

---

If you run into errors like this:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MyObject is not defined.
```

You may need to make a reference to the classes that could be created like so:

```
var ref1:Disk;
var ref2:Other;
var ref3:MyObject;
```

Comment: The problem I am having is this is for embedded media and using getDefinitionByName(str) throws an error that the class does not exist.  So getting to the line for displayObject doesn't happen

Comment: Would you be able to mock-up a quick example that I could look at?

Comment: `code`
[Embed(source="assets/disk.png")]
protected static const Fdisk:Class;
`code`

Then I load XML and in the XML I have a string "Fdisk"

`code`
var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(products[i].producticon) as Class;
`code`

I get the Error #1065: Variable Fdisk is not defined.

I even make reference to it before hand like

var _mDisk = new Fdisk();

No luck

Comment: Is fDisk part of a package? Such as com.things? If so you'll need to define the entire package in the string eg com.things.fDisk.

Comment: it was all part of the default package

Comment: Odd, I'll have to look into this further for you, sorry.

Comment: would it make more sense to package all of my media in a SWC in flash and include that into my project?

Comment: Definitely; maybe look at doing that first.